# What is the limit for the Rinne Tensei?

Tags: naruto

I know, that the Samsara of Heavenly Life is able to resurrect either all the individuals recently killed, or a single person from long ago. I know also, that this jutsu it's different from the Edo Tensei, since "It seems that this technique does not need the original body for the owner to be brought back, as Madara's original plan consisted of Obito reviving him at a time where the original body would have decomposed."

So the question is: does this technique have a weakness, or a time limit, after which you can't use it, or it's flawless?..If that's the case, could a Rinnegan user revive e.g. The Sage Of The Six Path?

Comment: Both Edo Tensei and Rinne Tensei requires the body or some DNA of the body (ie blood stains) to revive the respective person. Since SO6P has never been revived, we can pretty much conclude that no one has his DNA. Also recall about how people deliberate whether the SO6P even existed or not. It would make sense if the Sage destroyed all possible traces of his body after to prevent his revival.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, yes, the Sage of the Six Paths could be revived using this technique.

> the technique targets either all the individuals recently killed, or a single person from long ago.
>
> This technique can also be used on people brought back to life using Summoning: Impure World Reincarnation, transforming the debris and ash that forms the corpse vessel into a real body of living flesh and blood; even if they have been dead for many years.

But it seems to take a huge amount of chakra and be close to impossible to revive people without giving up your own life.

> This technique seemingly requires a massive amount of chakra, risking death in the process, as Konan feared the worst for Nagato when he used it after having previously expended so much chakra. After using the technique, Nagato became severely weakened; his hair became white due to overexertion of his chakra. **Obito's usage of the technique (even on a single target, as opposed to Nagato's use on a village's population) brought him to his inevitable death, as Black Zetsu noted.** [source](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Outer_Path:_Samsara_of_Heavenly_Life_Technique)

Comment: oh man...Obito's dead?...I think I'm gonna' hung myself up...since I've joined this site, I had died several times,honestly...

Comment: @Rinneg4n welcome to the world of potentional spoilers ^^

Comment: *SPOILER* Obito is still not dead.

Comment: Obito is not dead. Nor did the usage of Rinne Tensei kill him. Naruto wikia is dead wrong on this one.

Comment: @krikara Disagreed. After his edo tensei he was dieing for sure. Black zetsu attached himself onto him which was his only reason for survival up until now. As the black zetsu still did not detach hes still alive. Yet bound to die the moment he lets go.

Comment: @Dimitrimx Regardless, Obito is not dead. It doesn't matter if the sole reason for being alive is due to Black Zetsu keeping him alive. *Rinne tensei did not kill Obito*. The difference between dying and dead is huge. If Obito was dead, he wouldn't be in the process of attacking Madara at the moment.

Comment: obito is not only not dead, but instead saved naruto's ass using some crazy talk no jutsu..