# Could Sasuke revive his clan by using Samsara of Heavenly Life technique that Nagato used to revive Konoha's fallen?

Tags: naruto

When Kakashi asked Sasuke about his dream, Sasuke answers that his dream was to restore his clan and to kill Itachi.

> Since Itachi is dead, Sasuke has achieved half of his goal. Now, the only thing left is restoring his clan.

Could he use the Samsara of Heavenly Life technique to revive his clan?

Comment: PLEASE use the [spoiler markdown](http://anime.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) for spoilers.

Comment: Couldnt find so i made one by.my self

Comment: Please read the link I provided you.

Comment: not entire sure how any of this is a spoiler aside from maybe Sasuke achiving half of his dream. the rest (like him saying what his dream is) is made apparent in the second episode so that wouldn't really be a spoiler (it's like saying Naruto saying his's dream of becoming Hokage is a spoiler too)

Comment: Im spoiling about itachi

Comment: Sasuke's decision of using/not using the Outer Path techniques is opinion based. My opinion for example would be that the theme is looking forward and reviving the dead is living in the past and wouldn't restore the Uchiha. But I think a proper answer would relate to the limits of the said technique. So maybe the OP could edit the question in that regard.

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7701/what-is-the-limit-for-the-rinne-tensei has no accepted answer, but is in a right direction   i.e. the caster risks death due to the heavy requirement of chakra.

Answer (score 5):

Since Sasuke has the Rinnegan he should be able to use the Samsara of Heavenly Life Technique, but it will cost him his life since he is technically trading his life for the revival of others. He will also have to summon the King of Hell.

> Samsara of Heavenly Life Technique is a reincarnation ninjutsu used through the Outer Path, which can infuse new life into the bodies of those who have died **in exchange for the user's own life**.

Then the part about the King of Hell...

> To perform this technique, the user summons the King of Hell, which then releases the souls of the deceased from its mouth.

Source:

- [Outer Path-Samsara of Heavenly Life Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Outer_Path_%E2%80%94_Samsara_of_Heavenly_Life_Technique)

Comment: Though exact nature and limits of this are not known. But the caster doesn't exchange his life for others when using this jutsu. Konan clearly says something like "with his chakra level so low, Nagato will...". Impying it was the overuse of chakra that killed Nagato and not the technique. When originally used I thought it was time that was a factor in revival, i.e. only recently dead could be revived. But later use proves this as wrong. The only common thing I can see is that both were in reasonable distance from the people that they revived. There are other inconsistencies as well.

Comment: @Arcane you are actually wrong. Even the wikia says the user exchanges his/her life for the revival of the dead. Nagato was going to die because he had low chakra, but he decided to do the jutsu before he died (which killed him anyway). Then there was Obito, he was going to die, but Black Zetsu took over his body, which for some reason did not let him die at that moment.

Comment: @Arcane I am having extreme De Ja Vu to that comment. It feels like I am reading a comment I myself wrote a long time ago. That being said, I have to 100% agree on it. verbal explanations are inconsistent, but the facts remain that Obito did not die from using it, nor did he die from loosing the 10 tails

Comment: @Ms.Steel You die only if you completely empty your chakra reserve not if you're low on it. Thus if Nagato had stopped using his Ninjutsu he would've survived (especially considering his Uzumaki heritage). Wikia is not always right. http://prntscr.com/czqgad clearly shows that Konan is thinking that Nagato will die if he uses the jutsu. I've said before that I don't have the answer since there are several inconsistencies in the technique, but it is pretty clear that Nagato didn't die because he was low on chakra. Kakashi also survived chakra exhaustion (Fight vs Deidara)

Comment: @Ms.Steel Im with Arcane on this one. True complete exhasution of chakra will kill you. Best example was Kakashi, who agasint Deidara hung one by a thread due to excessive use of chakra, and actually died from it against Pein, saving Choji. Nagato was able to cast Rinne Rebirth, which proves he had more than enough chakra left to live. If you need more, look at Obito, who not only used Rinne Rebirth, but also had the 10 tails extracted from him, and hours later was alive and kicking (literally fighting an opponent)

Comment: @Ryan, Obito was going to die after using the Rinne Rebirth, but Black Zetsu attached himself to him and then said Obito will stay alive as long as he's attached to him (chap. 657). Then later on, Naruto used his Six Path's chakra to heal him (chap. 682), like he did to restore Kakashi's left eye (chap. 675).

Answer (score 2):

The above answer states the possibility that the Uchiha can be revived from by using [The Samsara of Heavenly Life Technique.](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Outer_Path_%E2%80%94_Samsara_of_Heavenly_Life_Technique)

**BUT**

Even though he can revive them using that technique, he needs the bodies of all the dead Uchiha in order infuse them with the souls released by the King of Hell. So it is **not possible** to revive them using the Samsara of Heavenly Life Technique.

However he can use the Summoning: Impure World Reincarnation Jutsu to revive his clan.

Comment: The question is asking if he COULD revive them, and I said yes as in he can but he will have to do some things first. I didn't want to go to much into detail in my answer, but I might add some stuff later.

Comment: ya, i can understand that. I just wanted to share what i know. No offence.

Comment: he would still need their bodies to get their DNA, and just as many sacrifices to do the summoning.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically, Sasuke should be able to bring back his clan members using [Outer Path — Samsara of Heavenly Life Technique](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Outer_Path_-_Samsara_of_Heavenly_Life_Technique), but as of Boruto,

> Sasuke has lost his Rinnegan due to Momoshiki controlling Boruto and stabbing it with a kunai knife. This has removed him of all of his Rinnegan's powers, such as Amenotejikara, Planetary Devastation, The Six Paths, and more.

Because of this, realistically speaking, Sasuke wouldn't be able to use Outer Path - Samsara of Heavenly Life Technique to revive his clansmen due to the reason above. Although, he should be able to hypothetically, only if he wants to.